# VS2003 - Metafile Crystal could not be opened

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2003

I'm working in a VS 2003 Application with .NET 2.0.
I dont know how to fix this erro bellow:

Metadata file 'c:...\CrystalDecisions.Shared.dll' could not be opened -- 'Version 2.0 is not a compatible version.'

i have version 13.0.2000.0 of Crystal instaled.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the version of Crystal Reports that you are using `13.0.2000.0` simply isn't supported in .NET 2.0 or Visual Studio 2003.

Based on [this support chart](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Which+Crystal+Reports+assembly+versions+are+supported+in+which+versions+of+Visual+Studio+.NET) it looks like Visual Studio 2012 would be the earliest version that supports `13.0.2000.0`, whereas support for Visual Studio 2003 ended with `12.0.1100.0`.

You can [download Visual Studio 2010 here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23507) or if you want the latest version of the IDE, you can download [Visual Studio Community Edition 2015 here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx).

Comment: I have VS 2010 and 2013 here, i realy need work on VS 2003, i can not convert this application. i will try downgrade my crystal reports version.

Comment: Based on the support chart, if you can use `12.0.1100.0`, it sounds like that should work for your 2003 application. Otherwise, it's likely that you would need to consider a conversion, which as you mentioned, isn't something you are interested in.